# How to stop Click Event when selecting the text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks

I have this Todo app in React. In the app when I click the `<h2>` item. It takes it to the edit mode. But When I try to select the text from the `<h2>`, it still takes it into the edit mode. I don't want that to happen. How can I stop that from happening? I think `window.getSelection()` is not working because the click is registered first and then the selection happens. So when the click is registered, it has no selected text.

Here is the necessary code block for the problem:

```
<h2 onClick={() => editTodo(index)}>{t.text}</h2>

function editTodo(index) {
  if(window.getSelection().toString()!=='')
    setList(list.map((x, i) => { if (i !== index) { return x } else { return { ...x, edit: true } } }))
}
```

I tried `window.getSelection()` as you can see but it's not working

Comment: Please add some more code. What does the list state looks like? How do you render the items (`h2`)?

Comment: @OriDrori What does it have to do with the mouse click event? I just want the mouse click event to stop when selecting the text.

Comment: How do you know that it's not related? If you knew, you could've answer the question yourself.

Comment: I want to make a working example, and I don't want to guess. In any case, how do you expect to cancel the edit mode?

Comment: @OriDrori I have added the whole code

Comment: I'm sure that you can find a middle ground between the problem + background, and the entire code :)

Comment: @OriDrori I am new to react. so don't know how much code do I need to share for this. 
:-(

Comment: Basic state. The element that has the problem, and whatever renders it. In you case: `list` state with an item or two in the array, the map that renders the `h2` / `input` + the edit and save buttons. You should also explain how to reproduce your problem - in your case you don't render the `h2` when in edit mode, so how can you select the text exactly?

Comment: yes. i can't select text when I am in edit mode. and to go to edit mode, i have to click on the ``<h2>``. but when i am not in the edit mode and try to select the text from ``h2``, it goes into the edit mode because eventually i have to click on the ``h2`` to select text from it and that takes it to the edit mode. now how can ii stop that from happening? I mean i don't want to go to edit mode when i am trying to select text. @OriDrori

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the `type` of the selection is "Range". If it is, don't update the state:

```
document.getSelection().type === 'Range'
```

Working example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Demo = () => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  
  function editTodo(index) {
    if (document.getSelection().type === 'Range') return;
    
    setEdit(true)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 
        onClick={() => editTodo()}
        onSelectStart={e => stopPropogation()}
        >text</h2>
      <div>Edit: {JSON.stringify(edit)}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

In addition, your `editTodo` function is a bit cumbersome, and you can make it a bit more concise (see comments in code):

```
function editTodo(index) {
  if(document.getSelection().type === 'Range') return; // bail out 

  setList(prevList => // use an updater functio get the previous state
    prevList.map((x, i) => // use an arrow function to avoid the need for explicit return
      i !== index // use a ternary instead of if/else
        ? x
        : { ...x, edit: true }
    )
  )
}
```